# How to prevent adobe xd uninstalling plugins automatically?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, adobe-xd, plugin

I am very new to adobe xd, and I have installed some of the plugins in it. But the problem is that whenever I clear my **%Temp%** and **Temp** data from my *windows* to speed up, all my plugins get uninstall automatically.

This is very time-consuming also, it's difficult to remember the plugin names again and again.

> Note: Sometimes without deleting the **%Temp%** and **Temp** files too, it gets uninstall automatically :(

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: This is a software support question, not necessarily a design one. Something you should ask probably in an Adobe forum or perhaps on [superuser.com]

Comment: There's probably a good lesson in this - stop throwing things away you *think* you don't need, as obviously you're missing some detail that makes this happen when you do. Don't try to out-think the computer.